# Removing files on a limit access backup server

Tags: backup, ftp, sftp, files

I have an account on a backup server but it's full, so I need to clear it. The problem is that

- It's only accessible via FTP, SFTP and Rsync (no shell)
- Deleting lots of small files (as in, multiple full Linux installations), which I have to do, is undoable over FTP/SFTP because it cannot recursively delete directories in one command (Yes, most clients will fake this by issueing all the seperate commands for you but the overhead is huge and the process takes several days...well it crashes before that).

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445643/how-to-delete-files-via-ftp-when-directory-has-over-100-000-files

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using WinSCP and it will delete the files one at a time without you needing to select each one, as WinSCP will issue the command to delete each file if needed.

Comment: A good FTP/SFTP client like Filezilla will do that too, that's not the problem. There are just so many files that the overhead of the commands becomes huge and it takes too long (e.g. several days but it crashes before that). I've added this into my question now.